# How to sort table using tablesorter.js plugin in 2-in-1 table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, web

need your help to solve my problem. I'm using Bootstrap table to show my data and divide my thead and tbody on two tables so user can scrolldown the tbody and thead stay on top or fixed.

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
 <thead>
   <tr class="active">
     <th>Coloumn1</th>
     <th>Coloumn2</th>
     <th>Coloumn3</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
</table>

<div class="scrollbar">
<table class="table table-bordered">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td>2.2</td>
      <td>2.3</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() 
   { 
     $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
   } 
   );
</script>
```

But when I tried to sort table data, there was nothing happen and I know it was caused by two tables.

Any solution guys so I could sort my data and keep using two tables? Thank you for your time.

Comment: check this -- http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

Comment: WOW!!! That's what I've been looking for. Thank you so much.. :D